# No such method error :

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Please assist, I am stack after a successful build. I learned myself Spring Hibernate, and I am not sure what could be issue this time, according to my research it says I have mismatching classes or api's.

Below is the error message :

2018-07-05 15:46:17.732  INFO 7440 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2018-07-05 15:46:18.556 ERROR 7440 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.clearCache()V
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.resetCommonCaches(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:575) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.mycompany.product.Application.main(Application.java:88) [classes/:na]
```

Below is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>product</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <!--  

    Spring boot   parent

    -->

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>

</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>

      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>

      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>

      <version>1.9.13</version>

</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>

         <dependency>

             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.0</version>
         </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0.pr3</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>function-sample-azure</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-sample</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.11.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</plugin>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <printSummary>true</printSummary>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>    
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>

     </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>


spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaumsdb
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


spring.jpa.properties.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

In addition: I have updated my netbeans from version 7 to version 8.2, I am just thinking perhaps it could be mismatch in versions.
I really don't have an idea what could be the problem.

Comment: I noticed that your POM has a mixture of Spring Boot and Spring dependencies. I suspect that they are pulling common dependencies of different versions. Do you really need the Spring dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

Your `pom.xml` is a mess, especially the `<dependency>` section e.g. why do you use Maven plugins as dependencies or why do you depend on Spring's SNAPSHOTs?

Generate a new template project using https://start.spring.io/ and add only the necessary dependencies.